# Parent onclick() event not being called when child div is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, parent-child

I have a situation where I have nested divs. I have a parent div (that has an onclick() event) and a few divs inside that are being dynamically populated.  I'm given to understand that through 'bubbling,' the onclick() event should propagate up through the DOM, triggering the onclick() event in all parents.  All of the research I have done has shown a bunch of people who are trying to PREVENT this, whereas I can't get it to work.  The only way I can get the onclick() to work, is to click near the edges of the div, presumably where the child divs don't exist, and I'm clicking directly on the parent.

I've included the applicable code below.  There can be as many as 9 of these, so-called "widgets" on the page, but I have removed all code except that referencing the first "widget".

Update: When I try to pull everything out of the JavaScript function, and put it directly in to the HTML code, it works as I would expect. However, doing this would force me to drop desired functionality, so I'm going to try to avoid that workaround.

There is a new fiddle below that shows essentially what I'm going for, even though the events are not calling the JS functions as I would expect.

Update #2: I have created a fiddle (#5 below) that mimics the response I'm seeing in the code.  When using the fiddle, you'll notice that no alert is given when clicking in the center of the div, but when you click near the outer boundaries of the div, you finally get a response.

PROBLEM SOLVED:

Per Racheet's answer below, this problem has been solved.  I have created a final Fiddle with the fully-functioning code for reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/8/

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function initializeWidgets(){

var widget1 = "Professional";

widget1 = 
    "<div class='outer'><div class='middle'>
    <div class='inner'><h1>" + widget1 + "</h1></div></div></div>";

document.getElementById("widget1").innerHTML = widget1;
}

function hoverWidgets(widgetID){
var w = new Array();
w[0] = "Work Experience, Educational History, and Resume Download";

w[widgetID-1] = "<div class='outer'><div class='middle'>
    <div class='inner'><h2>" + w[widgetID-1] + "</h2></div></div></div>";

document.getElementById("widget"+widgetID).innerHTML = w[widgetID-1];

}
```

APPLICABLE HTML:

```
<div class="widget" id="widget1" onclick="alert(1);" onmouseover="hoverWidgets('1')"
onmouseout="initializeWidgets()"></div>
```

CURRENT FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/5/

FINAL FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/8/

Comment: Click alert works across the entire div in the fiddle I've added above. Perhaps you should include more HTML, specifically the nested divs you mentioned.

Comment: I'm also getting JS errors in the console: "ReferenceError: hoverWidgets is not defined"

Comment: isherwood, the nested divs I was mentioning happen in the initializeWidgets() function and the hoverWidgets() function.  The child divs I'm talking about are the div class = "outer", "middle" and "inner" in those functions.

After further troubleshooting, I've discovered it is not specific to child divs.  I removed all of the child divs, and simply put an image in the parent div, and I'm getting the same response.  Could the problem be because the objects in the div are defined in a function, and are therefore, "out-of-scope" or something?

Comment: Please update your question rather than putting lengthy explanations in the comments. Have you resolved the JS errors? Update the fiddle if you have.

Comment: I have not resolved the problem.  I have created a new fiddle. However, I'm not well versed in how fiddle works.  It doesn't appear to be firing any of the JS functions I created, but you should get a good idea of what I'm going for.

Comment: That almost certainly means there's a problem with your JS. SO users create hundreds of fiddles every day, so it's a reliable platform for testing.

Comment: That makes sense, and I trust you're correct. I am unable to locate the problem, and, except for the onclick problem I'm having, when I execute this code locally, it fires the functions as I would expect.  I even removed all of the code in the functions, replacing with just an alert, and I still got no response. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Whatever is the problem with JS, as you describe, is also the problem here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/3/.  I have to defer to those who are more familiar with fiddle, as I'm new to SO, and Fiddle.

Comment: I've found your problem. It is a jsfiddle issue. If you leave the second dropdown on the left to "onload", then your function is wrapped in a call to the document.onload handler. Which means that the initializeWidgets() function is scoped locally to that handler. If you set that dropdown to "No wrap - in <head>" your fiddle works properly. - http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/4/

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I have updated the question above with a new Fiddle that mimics the response I am seeing in my code.

Comment: I've just looked through the css on your fiddle. It's nice to see that you're using modern affordances like -moz-box-shadow, but using "display:table" and "display:table-cell" to render anything besides non-tabular data feels very 2003.

Comment: Racheet, I don't disagree.  I spent the better part of a day trying to figure out how to center things 'vertically' in the divs.  After all kinds of experimenting and research, that method was the only way that worked.  If you have a suggestion that centers things vertically, without using the display:table, etc. and/or without nesting the content in 3 divs, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I've not had a comprehensive look for a solution, but I'd probably start by setting your <h1> and <h2> elements to display:block and then adding a whole load of top margin and bottom margin to them. If there's the same amount of top and bottom margin, then they should be centered vertically inside their parent element. By setting them to display:block you can kill the need for your inner div, and get the same effect by playing with their margin and padding.

Comment: That was originally how I started, but I can have as many widgets as I want on a page, and they can have any amount of content in them.  Even more, the widgets will eventually be populated dynamically from my database, so the top and bottom margin will not be consistent from one widget to the next.  This conversation is out of scope of this question though, feel free to message me if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played with your example a fair bit and worked out the problem. Here is my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/v3MGX/7/

```
    window.initializeWidgets = (function() {
    /*THIS SECTION IS YOUR WIDGET CONSTRUCTOR*/

    //Set up your constants for this widget
    var widget1 = "Professional";
    var widget2 = "Work Experience, Educational History, and Resume Download";

    //first you grab your old element
    var widgetSmallElement = document.getElementById("widget1");

    //then you make your new elements
    var outer = document.createElement("div");
    outer.setAttribute('class','middleSmall');
    var inner = document.createElement("div");
    inner.setAttribute('class','innerSmall');
    var heading = document.createElement("h1");
    heading.innerHTML = widget1;
    var subHeading = document.createElement("h2");
    subHeading.innerHTML = widget2;

    //now you chain the above and then add them to the document
    inner.appendChild(heading);
    outer.appendChild(inner);
    widgetSmallElement.appendChild(outer);

    //This is your new, simplified hoverWidgets handler
    window.hoverWidgets = function (widgetID) {
        inner.replaceChild(subHeading,inner.firstChild);        
    };

    /*THIS SECTION IS THE RETURN VALUE FROM YOUR CONSTRUCTOR*/
    return function() {
        //this is the function actually given to the onClick and onMouseout handler as the initializeWidgets funciton.
        inner.replaceChild(heading,inner.firstChild);
    };

})();
```

The problem you're having is due to the way you are creating your inner divs. When you create a html element in javascript by writing html as a string into a DOM node's innerHTML property the old node that was there is deleted, and a new one is created to replace it.

When that old node is deleted the event handlers that were attached to it are also deleted, so when your mouseovers are running, they're actually deleting and re-creating the various inner divs, *and their existing event handlers*. Because of this, the onclick handler you assigned in the html doesn't exist for those inner nodes.

It's usually a bad idea to add html to a document by directly writing into the innerHTML property.

I've rewritten the solution so that it creates the nodes natively in JavaScript, and then re-written the initializeWidgets and hoverWidgets functions to simply swap between the <h1> and <h2> nodes inside the inner div.

I've put the whole thing inside a closure to stop it polluting the global scope with anything but the initializeWidgets and hoverWidgets functions.  This implementation will only work if it's registered as a handler for the onLoad function, since the constructor part of it will need to run and create those two functions before the html tries to attach them as event handlers.

If you find this solution to complex for your needs, you should still be able to create your own solution by using javascript to create and manipulate the divs and h1/h2 tags natively rather than doing it by writing directly into the innerHTML property.

[Here's a guide on how to do that](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml)

Comment: This is great, and I suspect it will be exactly what I need, and I am ALMOST there.  Apparently I need just one more little nudge.  When you say the implementation works only if registered as a handler for the onLoad function.  By that, do you mean:

'<body onload="initializeWidgets()">'

This does not appear to be working for me

Comment: if you're in chrome, go to the jsfiddle and right click on the frame that's displaying the output and ask it to "show frame source", you'll see what I mean there.

Comment: GREAT! Thank you sir! I have update the fiddle with a few minor changes (cosmetic, just so the text is centered vertically in the div).  I will add the link to the fiddle in the question.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If your on-click isn't somehow referencing the DIV specifically, could always add the onclick to the other nested divs.... otherwise, you need to post more of your html.

Comment: There really isn't much more HTML to post. See the fiddle posted above.